# javascript floating point with ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
`function editTrans(t){
            var userid = t;
            alert(userid)
            if (userid != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'load.php?',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {userid: userid},
                    success: function(response){ 
                        $('.modal-body').html(response); 
                        $('#loadTransportUpadtae').modal('show'); 
                    }
                });
            }
        }

$idclient = 6; 
$idR= 100;
$passAcross          = $idclient .'.'.$idR;

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info userinfo" onclick="editTrans(<?php echo $passAcross; ?>)" >Edit Note</button>`
```

I have a challenge, $idR is an id for a particular field, and $idclient is another value on a particular field, when I pass the values it works but I have a challenge with values that has an ending part to be o, e.g 100, 100, 40. The javascript treats it as a floating point and removes the zero.

How can I pass those values without removing the zeros?

```
`function editTrans(t){
            var userid = t;
            alert(userid)// expecting this to have 6.100
            if (userid != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'load.php?',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {userid: userid},
                    success: function(response){ 
                        $('.modal-body').html(response); 
                        $('#loadTransportUpadtae').modal('show'); 
                    }
                });
            }
        }

$idclient = 6; 
$idR= 100;
$passAcross          = $idclient .'.'.$idR;
```

I am expecting the function to pick the floating part plus the zero

Comment: Quote the value: `editTrans('<?= $passAcross; ?>')`

Comment: how can you echo out the value with this editTrans('<?= $passAcross; ?>')

Comment: Please read the [PHP tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) documentation article.

Comment: it is still leaving the zeros behind, like 34.100, it will pick 34.1 instead of 34.100

Comment: In my environment the '6.100' string is beeing passed correctly to the function and through ajax request (FF, Chrome, both fine). This string might be converted to number only if some additional operations are applied to it.